# PME Journal 1:9; is there any justification for solving linear linear equation with this method?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

In the *PME Journal* volume 1, issue 9, archived in [here](http://www.pme-math.org/journal/issues/PMEJ.Vol.1.No.9.pdf), in page 359 it is given that

[image]

However, is there any justification for solving system of linear equation with this method ?

The author only provides some examples for this method in the continuation of the article, and there is not even a word why this method works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are (essentially) using a 'multiply and subtract' technique to simplify the equations.

E.g. Multiply 1) by $d_2$ and 2) by $d_1$. Subtract and you get 4).

You get 5) analogously with $d_3$ and $d_2$ on 2) and 3). Then, using the same idea, multiply 4) by $A_2$ and 5) by $A_1$, subtract and you get

$$|A_1B_2|y + |A_1C_2|z = 0$$

whence $\frac{y}{z} = \frac{-|A_1C_2|}{|A_1B_2|}$ or $y:z = -|A_1C_2|:|A_1B_2|$.

The same thing again gives the proportion for $x$. Once you have the proportions, you can substitute and solve for the values if necessary.